# Calculating the number of dots lie above and below the regression line with R

Tags: r, linear-regression

How do I calculate the number of dots that lie above and below the regression line on a scatter plot?

```
data = read.csv("info.csv")
par(pty = "s")
plot(data$col1, data$col2, xlab = "xaxis", ylab = "yaxis", xlim = c(0, 
  1), cex.lab = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5, ylim = c(0, 1), col.lab = "red", 
  col = "blue", pch = 19)
abline(a = -1.21, b = 2.21)
```

Comment: thanks for showing your code, but it's still not **reproducible** code since we don't have access to `info.csv`.  Please take a look at http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
x <- 1:10
set.seed(1)
y <- 2*x+rnorm(10)

plot(y~x)

fit <- lm(y~x)
abline(fit)

resi <- resid(fit)
#below the fit:
sum(resi < 0)
#above the fit:
sum(resi > 0)
```

**Edit:**
If you did (for some unknown reason) something like this:

```
x <- 1:10
set.seed(1)
y <- 2*x+rnorm(10)

plot(y~x)
abline(-0.17,2.05)
```

You can do this:

```
yfit <- 2.05 * x - 0.17
resi <- y - yfit

sum(resi < 0)
sum(resi > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I used an equation to draw the line of best fit like this. fit= abline(a=-1.21, b=2.12). Plot is correct but the value of fit is null. How to change your code to use this equation?

Comment: @user1731629 See my edit to the answer. However, I wonder where you got the parameters for `abline()`.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I have shown my program.

Comment: You should be able to figure that out: `x <- data$col1; y <- data$col2`.

Answer (score 1):

If I've read the question properly, the answer would be.

1. Determine the equation of the regression line - it is straight and there will be of the form y = mx +b where m is the slope of the line and b is the y intercept.
2. Calculate the y value for each x in the domain of x.
3. Using the value of y that you have in your data, determine whether it is greater, equal to or less than the calculated value of y

Using the above should be sufficient to find the numbers (counts) you are after.